# Warum „Das ist der Bus, …“, wenn es doch „der Bus“ ist?

Tags: idiom, definite-article, demonstrative-pronoun

Ich habe es so gelernt:

> Da kommt ein Bus.
>
> <s>**Der** ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.</s>
>
> <s>**Er** ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.</s>
>
> **Das** ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.

Warum sagt man nicht „der“ oder “er“, sondern „das“?

Comment: »Das« can be an article (»the« in english), but also a pronoun (a »relative pronoun« to be more precise). Here it is a pronoun (it's not »the« but »this« in english: »**This** is not **the** bus we take«)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ist "das" hier nicht ein Demonstrativpronomen? "Das dort ist ..."

Comment: @what: Nein. Siehe https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/pronomen/relativpronomen und https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/pronomen/demonstrativpronomen

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das sind aber schöne Beispiele für meine Behauptung ;-)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich zitiere aus Deinem zweiten Link: "*Anstelle von jener/jene/jenes bevorzugen wir in der Alltagssprache meist der/die/das da bzw. der/die/das dort*". Sofern wir also im Satz *der/die/das* durch *jener/jene/jenes* ersetzen können, ist es ein Demonstrativpronomen. *Jener ist nicht der Bus, den...* und *Das/dies ist nicht der Bus, ...* sind gleichwertig verwendbar, somit ist *das* in diesem Fall ein Demonstrativpronomen. Was übrigens durch deinen Hinweis, dass es im Englischen *this* heißen muss noch unterstrichen wird, denn *this* ist ein Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: Wer oder was, der oder das.

Answer (score 8):

It has to read

> Das ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.

*That one isn't the bus we are going to take.*

**Das** is used as a "weak" demonstrative pronoun. You could also say

> Dies ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.

But you are looking for

> Diese**r** ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.

which has the "correct" gender. You would use the latter one only when pointing fingers at the bus in question, or pat it.

The reason why "das" and "dies" can also be used is they aren't referring to the bus but to a vaguely defined object (which happens to be the bus). These are neuter by default.

> Ist das ihr Mann?

*Is that one your husband?*

> Nein, das ist er nicht.

*No, that one isn't him.*

Comment: "Dieser ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen." sounds somewhat old-fashioned and said like that in everyday life would surely be considered funny.

Comment: I would use it when pointing fingers. *Nicht der da. Dieser da!*

Answer (score 1):

The "das" is not referring to the gender of the bus. You could replace it by e.g. "dies".

Furthermore your sentence has a mistake in it. The correct way would be: "Das ist nicht **der** Bus, den wir nehmen". The **der** ist now reffering to the gender of the Bus!

Example with **die Kiste**: "Das ist nicht **die** Kiste, welche/die ich meinte" - This is not the box I meant.

Example with **das Mädchen**: "Das ist **das** Mädchen, welches/das ich mag. - This is the girl I like

Comment: Why do you use "welche/welches" in your examples and not "die/das"?

Comment: @Iris Same reason as the "das/dies", you can say "Das ist das Mädchen, das ich mag" as well. But then you have the "das" doubled. Furthermore in the case of the "das" and the comma, you could get confused about using "das" or "dass".

Comment: @Artery thats an easy to answer thing, if you can replace 'dass' with 'dieses' or 'welches' then it is a 'dass', otherwise it is 'das'.

Comment: @Videonauth I know that rule, thats not the point. This was just one smaller reason. The main reason is, that I just have choosen them, without thinking about it, like you could have replaced the "das" with "dies". It doesn't matter in the end.

Answer (score 1):

> **Das** ist nicht der Bus, den wir nehmen.
>
> *Der* fährt in die falsche Richtung.

Prinzipiell hast du tatsächlich beide Möglichkeiten. In einem Satz mit *der* steht dieses *der* stellvertretend für »der Bus«, es sollte also möglich sein, das Wort *Bus* dazwischenzuschreiben. Das *das* ist hingegen ein schwächeres Demonstrativpronomen, das wie *dies* keinen Hinweis auf das grammatikalische Geschlecht des »Zielworts« hat. Umgangssprachlich wird – vor allem von Kindern – gerne ein *da* dazugesetzt:

> Das da ist der falsche Bus.

In deinem Beispielsatz ist das Demonstrativpronomen *das* die bessere Wahl, denn ein Satz wie »der Bus ist nicht der Bus« verwirrt. *Der Bus* wird weiter hinten wieder aufgegriffen, vorne ist also nur ein kurzer Hinweis nötig.

Wenn du einen Satz mit *der* verwenden kannst, kannst du meistens auch *er* stattdessen benützen:

> Ist das unser Bus?
>
> Den nehmen wir nicht. Er fährt in die falsche Richtung.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the answer is pretty easy.

The intent of this statement is to point out that the item being talked about is not the correct item. The german word for item is "Ding".

The word "Ding" requires the article "Das" and not "Der" or "Die".

> Das ist das Ding.

Examples:

> Das ist nicht die richtige Bahn.
>
> Das hat mir aber Spaß gemacht.
>
> Das ist eine (die)Pflanze.
>
> Das ist ein (der)Baum.